# Extend inner array in 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I've got two numpy arrays, with shapes something like:

`A = (2000, 2000, 3)`
and
`B = (2000, 2000, 4)`

I also have an array of indices, let's say `[1,3]`

What I need to do is take the two original arrays, and create a new array that is `(2000, 2000, 5)` where each inner array is the entire contents of A's inner array, and the specified indices of B's.

So an inner array might be:

`(A[0], A[1], A[2], B[1], B[3])`

I'm currently doing this directly in Python, like this:

```
width = 2000
height = 2000
out_data = np.empty((height, width, 5), np.float32)
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        out_data[y][x][:3] = A[y][x]
        out_data[y][x][3] = B[y][x][1]
        out_data[y][x][4] = B[y][x][3]
```

This is very slow. What I'm wondering is if there's a better way that I can do this within numpy?

If there's a way to do this by extending `A`, I am happy with that, as `A` and `B` are only used for this purpose.

Comment: How about providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result?

Comment: Does this work ```np.concatenate((A,B[...,idx]),axis=2)``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
ix = [1, 3]
new = np.c_[A, B[:, :, ix]]
```

### Minimal example

```py
width = 5
height = 5

A = np.arange(np.prod((width, height, 3))).reshape(width, height,3)
B = -np.arange(np.prod((width, height, 4))).reshape(width, height,4)
```

OP's code:

```py
ix = [1, 3]  # or (1, 3)
out_data = np.empty((height, width, 5), A.dtype)
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        out_data[y][x][:3] = A[y][x]
        out_data[y][x][3] = B[y][x][1]
        out_data[y][x][4] = B[y][x][3]
```

This solution:

```py
new = np.c_[A, B[:, :, ix]]

>>> np.array_equal(out_data, new)
True
```

### Speed

```py
width = 2000
height = 2000

# ...

# time of OP's: 9.55s

%timeit np.c_[A, B[:, :, ix]]
# 143 ms ± 42.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks - this is really helpful and exactly what I was hoping. I ended up going with np.concatenate(), but you get the answer for being so thorough!

Answer (score 1):

The following does the same as your code in vectorized manner, without the for loops:

```
out = np.empty((2000, 2000, 5))
out[:, :, :3] = A
out[:, :, 3:5] = B[:, :, [1,3]]
```

Comment: The slice `1:3` doesn't get the right rows from B if they're not sequential (like in the example).

Comment: yes you're right!

Answer (score 1):

You can [`dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) you arrays along the last axis:

```
out_data = np.dstack([A, B[:,:,[1,3]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `np.concatenate` like this for your example.

```py
np.concatenate((a, b[:,:,(1,3)]), axis=2)
```

On 2000x2000 arrays as input, this ran about 61 times as fast as your original code and roughly equal to the direct index.